# Maven copy properties files

Tags: maven

I am not very used to use Maven. I want to copy the `messages.properties` file to a directory out of standard `WEB-INF`. I want it to be within `WEB-INF` and also in another directory in order to access it from Javascript. I cannot access anything under `WEB-INF` in my web application and I have strings that I need to fetch in `js` files for the i18n.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this in the Maven build?

Answer (score 0):

You should place such resources within `src/main/webapp` directory, so they are effectively in a root of `war` file.

Comment: The problem is that JSF is configured to get the messages.properties from src/main/resources and I don't want to change this. So the solution is to copy the files to another dir. Then I have the properties deployed in both directories whereas I still got only one instance in my web application. When I make changes, I make them only in this instance and when it is deployed to the server, it's deployed in both directories. That helps me access the message.properties from JSF without changing anything and from javascript files (from the other directory not in WEB-INF).